# Tkinter: Integers as labels overwrite

Tags: python, tkinter, label

I am creating labels in a for loop that display integers every time I fire an event (a mouse click) on my application. The problem is that old labels don't get erased and the new ones come on top of them causing a big mess.
Here is the working code that you can try out:

```
import numpy as np
import Tkinter as tk

class Plot(object):

    def __init__(self, win):
        self.win = win

        self.bu1 = tk.Button(win,text='Load',command=self.populate,fg='red').grid(row=0,column=0)

        self.listbox = tk.Listbox(win, height=5, width=5)
        self.listbox.grid(row=1,column=0)#, rowspan=10, columnspan=2)
        self.listbox.bind("<Button-1>", self.print_area)

    def populate(self):
        """Populate listbox and labels"""

        self.time = [1,2,3]
        self.samples = ['a','b','c']
        for item in self.time:
            self.listbox.insert(tk.END,item)

        for i,v in enumerate(self.samples):
            tk.Label(self.win, text=v).grid(row=2+i,column=0,sticky=tk.W)

        self.lbl_areas = []
        for i in range(0, len(self.samples)):
            self.lbl=tk.IntVar()
            self.lbl.set(0)
            self.lbl_areas.append(tk.Label(self.win,textvariable=self.lbl).grid(row=2+i,column=1,sticky=tk.W))  

    def print_area(self, event):
        """Prints the values"""

        widget = event.widget
        selection=widget.curselection()
        value = widget.get(selection[0])

        #Here is the dictionary that maps time with values
        self.d = {1:[('a',33464.1),('b',43.5),('c',64.3)],
             2:[('a',5.1),('b',3457575.5),('c',25.3)],
             3:[('a',12.1),('b',13.5),('c',15373.3)]}

        lbl_val = []
        for i in range(0, len(self.samples)):
            lbl_val.append(self.d[value][i][1])


        for i in range(0, len(self.samples)):
            self.lbl=tk.IntVar()
            self.lbl.set(lbl_val[i])
            tk.Label(self.win,textvariable=self.lbl).grid(row=2+i,column=1,sticky=tk.W)         


 def main():
     root = tk.Tk()
     app = Plot(root)
     tk.mainloop()

 if __name__ == '__main__':
     main()
```

If You try to run this code and click on LOAD you will see the numbers appearing in the listbox and labels a,b,c with values set to zero at the beginning. If you click on the number in the listbox the values (mapped into the dictionary d) will appear but you will see the overwrite problem. How can I fix that?

How can I overcome this problem? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Don't create new labels. Create the labels once and then update them on mouse clicks using the `configure` method of the labels.

OR, before creating new labels delete the old labels.If you design your app so that all of these temporary labels are in a single frame you can delete and recreate the frame, and all of the labels in the frame will automatically get deleted. In either case (destroying the frame or destroying the individual labels) you would call the `destroy` method on the widget you want to destroy.

Comment: How would I delete the old labels? I have tried to use self.lbl.destroy() at the end of the for loop but that does not solve the problem. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @diegus: you call the `destroy` method on the label. If that didn't work, you did it wrong. Without seeing actual code it's impossible to say what you did wrong.

Comment: @Oakley I made an edit including part of the application (hope this help), where should I call the destroy method?

Comment: @diegus: you have to keep a list of the widget that you can create so that you can iterate over them later.